# Sub string in excel

Tags: string, excel

I would like to substring tow strings from tow different columns

How the first string in column A1 Looks like:
**A76  Transfer Conditions for Tools and Equipment**

How the string in the column B1 Looks like:
**Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/Circular-A76.pdf**

What I would like to have is

From the second string the last bit after the last **/**

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/","@",LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"/","")))))
```

And from the first string I would like to have the Hole thing

So the string at the and should look like:
Circular-A76.pdf | A76  Transfer Conditions for Tools and Equipment

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write in C1 cell with `=RIGHT($B1,SMALL(IF(MID($B1,LARGE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1)))),1)="/",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($B1))),""),1)-1) & " | " & $A1`

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You will get
[image]